# Custom labels with placeholder in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, customlabel, label, spring17

I'm using Custom Labels on a Visualforce page but those needs to contain a variable inside them, I'm used to it like this in Lightning:

```
{!format($Label.c.myLabel, v.attribute1, v.attribute2)}
```

Where $Label.c.myLabel has a placeholder as this: {0}, {1}.

I can't find the proper way to do it as this in a VF page.

Comment: How do you want to display the info ? {0},{1} to 0,1 ?

Comment: I would like to display variable that I pass to it in place of the {0} and {1}

Comment: You want to display info like. If {0} then display "A", if placeholder {1} then Display "B" ?

Comment: No, I want to use it  like I do in lightning so if my label is like "The total price is {0}" and my attribute is equal to 500 it displays to "The total price is 500"

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following way in a VF page:

```
<apex:outputText value="{! $Label.myLabel}">
    <apex:param value="MyParameter"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that in apex controller using

> String label = System.Label.myLabel;
>
> List argList = new List();
>
> argList.add(arg1);
>
> argList.add(arg2);
>
> String formatedString = String.format(label,argList);